# How do I find where an instance of a Java singleton is created?

Tags: java, singleton, instance

In a large, complex program it may not be simple to discover where in the
code a Singleton has been instantiated. What is the best approach to keep track of created singleton instances in order to re-use them?

Regards,
RR

Comment: Do you want to know which call did instantiate the singleton (assuming lazy instantiation)? If so, you can modify the singleton to store / log the stack trace when it calls the constructor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) usually has a private constructor, thus the Singleton class is the only class which can instantiate the one and only singleton instance.

Comment: @recolnrelax could you please add a snippet which shows what you actually do. (I don't understand the part 'the variable assigned to that singleton)

Comment: i wasn't reading it right. "the Singleton class is the only class which can instantiate the one and only singleton instance" i got it now :p sorry

Answer (score 1):

It's the responsibilty of `singleton class` developer to make sure that the instance is being reused on multiple calls.

As a user, you shouldn't worry about it.

```
class Singelton
{
    private static Singelton _singelton = null;

    private Singelton()
    {

    }

    // NOT usable for Multithreaded program
    public static Singelton CreateMe()
    {
        if(_singelton == null)
            _singelton = new Singelton();
        return _singelton;        
    }
}
```

Now, from anywhere in your code, you can instantiate `Singelton`, how many times you like and each time assign it to different reference. but c'tor is called ONLY once.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an `enum`

```
enum Singleton {
    INSTANCE:
}
```

or something similar which cannot be instantiated more than once and globally accessible.

Answer (score 0):

General practice for naming methods which create/return singletons is `getInstance()`. I don't understand the situation when you can't find the place in code where singletons created, but you can search for this method name.

If you want to catch the exact moment of singleton creation - you can use [AOP](http://jac.ow2.org/docs/introduction.html). AspectJ is a good example in java. You will be able to execute your code before/after creation of class or calling `getInstance()` method.

If your question is about reusing of created Singletons, then search this site. [For example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5179893/c-sharp-singleton-code-reuse)