# How to make a generic singleton base class C#

Tags: c#, generics, singleton

I am trying to create a generic singleton base class like

```
public class SingletonBase<T> where T : class, new()
{
    private static object lockingObject = new object();
    private static T singleTonObject;
    protected SingletonBase()
    {

    }

    public static T Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return InstanceCreation();
        }
    }
    public static T InstanceCreation()
    {
        if(singleTonObject == null)
        {
             lock (lockingObject)
             {
                  if(singleTonObject == null)
                  {
                       singleTonObject = new T();
                  }
             }
        }
        return singleTonObject;
    }
}
```

But I have to make constructor as public in derived one.

```
public class Test : SingletonBase<Test>
{
    public void A()
    {

    }
    private Test()
        : base()
    { }
}
```

Compilation Error:

> 'Test' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Test'

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I think this answer is probably quite relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/380771/120243

Comment: I think your sample code is wrong. It builds fine. Just a guess, but I think you meant that your error was related to `PermissionController` in which case `PermissionController` must have a public paramerterless constructor to satisfy the `new()` constraint on `T`.

Comment: @AlastairPitts :- That answer still is not singleton.

Comment: @JasonWatkins :- Thanks for pointing error. I updated the sample code.

Comment: @DJ Yes it is. It doesn't use locking as it's using statics, but it's definitely a singleton. It probably should have a static constructor, but it's completely valid. See: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx

Comment: @Alastair It _does_ have an implicit static constructor. For nearly all practical purposes the field assignment in the class can be considered part of the static constructor. adding an empty explicit static constructor changes absolutely nothing practically speaking.

Comment: Actually it's not thread safe: `singleTonObject = new T();` use temporary `variable var temp = new T(); singleTonObject = temp;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is your generic constraint `where T : class, new()`. The `new()` constraint requires a public, parameterless constructor on T. There is no way around this; you need to provide such a constructor in `Permission Controller`.

Comment: +1. this is actually the correct answer to OP's original issue. My answer had more to do with the overall design pattern.

Comment: hmm.. OK.. I think I need to choose some other direction. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I would avoid this kind of recursive generic pattern. Read this [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/03/curiouser-and-curiouser.aspx) for a detailed explanation of the pattern and reasons *not* to use it.

As far as I can tell, you don't need to have any sub-classes of `SingletonBase<T>`. I can't see anything that a subclass of `SingletonBase<T>` would be able to add to your code. I would simply rewrite it as

```
public static class Singleton<T> where T : class, new()
{
    ...
}
```

You can then use it as

```
var test = Singleton<Test>.Instance;
```

If you want to be able to use `Test` as a singleton, create it as

```
public class Test 
{
    public static T Instance
    {
        get { return Singleton.Instance<Test>; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Presumably the posted code is a reduced test case.

Comment: Could you please explain how you think the linked blog post applies to this question? I don't see it.

Comment: @JasonWatkins it applies to the pattern OP is using -- `class Test : Singleton<Test>`.

Comment: But that's Eric's post is talking about recursive *constraints*, not simple inheritance from a generic class.

Comment: @JasonWatkins It's true OP's code did not contain recursive constraints, but it was probably intended to be used as though it did. I think it's implicit in the singleton pattern. After all `Foo : Singleton<Bar>` would mean `Foo.Instance` is a `Bar` -- which may be valid, but kind of breaks the whole singleton design pattern.