# Generic abstract base class for singletons (C#) - cannot instantiate the private Lazy instance

Tags: c#, generics, singleton, abstract-base-class

I currently have a collection of 6 or 7 singletons, all of which do almost the same thing (see the `For` method in the below example) but with a different internal DB query and return a collection of different objects (so parsing the DB results is different in each singleton).

Therefore, using [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16745629/how-to-abstract-a-singleton-class) as my base, I've been trying to build an abstract generic base class in C# for these singletons.

There are [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15607454/how-to-make-a-generic-singleton-base-class-c-sharp) on SO but none implement `Lazy`, which I wish to.

So far I have this

```
public abstract class SingletonBase<T> where T : class, new()
{
    private static Lazy<SingletonBase<T>> _lazy;
    private static readonly object _lock = new object();

    public static SingletonBase<T> Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_lazy != null && _lazy.IsValueCreated)
            {
                return _lazy.Value;
            }

            lock (_lock)
            {
                if (_lazy != null && _lazy.IsValueCreated)
                {
                    return _lazy.Value;
                }

                *****  this is the problem line  *****
                _lazy = new Lazy<SingletonBase<T>>(new T());
            }

            return _lazy.Value;
        }
    }

    public abstract IEnumerable<T> For(string systemLangCode);
}
```

However, a problem occurs on the line

```
_lazy = new Lazy<SingletonBase<T>>(new T());
```

Visual Studio tells me "Cannot resolve constructor 'Lazy<T>'."

I'm unsure what should be passed into the constructor for `Lazy<SingletonBase<T>>`, or have I gone in the wrong direction?

Comment: why even use generics? Is there a reason for that?

Comment: Some standard techniques for doing singletons are shown here: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx

Comment: @T_D: that's a valid question and I don't truly have an answer, other than when I was looking around for other singleton base classes the other examples used generics.

Comment: @dbc: I've already read that article - more than once - but it doesn't cover using it as a derivable base class.

Comment: @awj: "it doesn't cover using it as a derivable base class" - please, tell us, what singleton-related functional are you going to derive and override?

Comment: @Dennis: I've updated the OP with more of an explanation.

Comment: I wouldn't use inheritance here. The boilerplate for a `Lazy<T>` based singleton is so short that I wouldn't worry about repetition.

Comment: `Lazy<T>` already supports locking, so no need for your lock. Pretty much the whole point of that class is that it abstracts locking away.

Comment: a static constructor would achieve the same as a Lazy class in  your case here

Comment: I also want to note that you should not access the database in classic singletons. Database accessing singletons should be IoC singletons instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite some great advice, I still wanted to use a singleton to provide a solution because I felt I could so this in less and simpler code. And here is what I did.

Here is the generic base class.

```
public abstract class SingletonBase<S, T> where S : class, new()
{
    protected static readonly Dictionary<string, List<T>> Dictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<T>>();
    private static readonly S _instance = new S();
    private static readonly object _lock = new object();

    public static S Instance
    {
        get
        {
            lock (_lock)
            {
                return _instance;
            }
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> For(string systemLangCode)
    {
        systemLangCode = systemLangCode.ToLower();

        if (!Dictionary.ContainsKey(systemLangCode))
        {
            PopulateDictionary(systemLangCode);
        }

        return Dictionary.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Key == systemLangCode).Value;
    }

    protected abstract void PopulateDictionary(string systemLangCode);
}
```

What I'm actually doing in here, aside from instantiating and caching an instance of the derived type, `S`, is handling requests for a collection of `T`. Rather than querying the DB for, and storing all possible recordsets, I query for a recordset when needed, using `systemLangCode` as a variable in the query, parse this recordset into a `List<T>`, and then store this collection in `Dictionary` using `systemLangCode` as the key.

Therefore, a query is only made if this resultset has not been previously obtained by that singleton.

And here is a derivation of the above base class.

```
public sealed class Languages : SingletonBase<Languages, Language>
{
    protected override void PopulateDictionary(string systemLangCode)
    {
        var languages = new List<Language>();

        // some DB stuff

        Dictionary.Add(systemLangCode, languages);
    }
}
```

This base class now allows me to build a series of derived classes which contain little more than the database query. Thus, I now have a single definition of a singleton which I can use for storing, for example, a collection of languages in different languages, a collection of countries in different languages, a collection of timezones in different languages, *etc*.

An example of usage:

```
var langsDe = Languages.Instance.For("de");
var langsEn = Languages.Instance.For("en");
```

And if I later call

```
var langsDe = Languages.Instance.For("de");
```

Then this will be retrieved from the internal `Dictionary`.

Answer (score 1):

> or have I gone in the wrong direction?

Looks like this.

First of all, `_lazy` field has a type of `Lazy<SingletonBase<T>>`. Hence, you can't pass `T` instance into its constructor.

The only option here is to pass a delegate, which returns instance of `SingletonBase<T>`-derived type (since `SingletonBase<T>` is abstract). Obviously, you need a way to obtain this instance. And now note, that this is a code of a **static** property getter in abstract class.

How do you plan to do this?
You can't override static method or property.

The second, what's the profit from a singleton, which wraps `Lazy<T>`?
Why just don't create thread-safe `Lazy<T>`:

```
var singleton = new Lazy<YourClass>(true);
```

or:

```
var singleton = new Lazy<YourClass>(SomeMethodThatCreatesYourClass, true);
```

**UPD**.

According to edits of your question, you are trying to mix two responsibilities:

- the creation of singleton object;
- the creation of `T` objects from database.

This isn't a way to go.
You need a base *factory* class (or even an interface, if there's no any logic, that could be implemented in base class):

```
abstract class Factory<T>
{
    public abstract IEnumerable<T> For(string systemLangCode);
}
```

Then, you need to create a number of descendants, e.g.:

```
class Factory1 : Factory<YouClass1> {}
class Factory2 : Factory<YouClass2> {}
// etc
```

Then, if you want them to be the singletons, you just have to wrap particular factories into `Lazy<T>` instances, e.g.:

```
static class Singletons
{
    private static readonly Lazy<Factory1> factory1;
    private static readonly Lazy<Factory2> factory2;

    static Singletons()
    {
        factory1 = new Lazy<Factory1>(true); // or Lazy<Factory1>(() => /* */, true)
        factory2 = new Lazy<Factory2>(true); // or Lazy<Factory2>(() => /* */, true)
    }

    public Factory1 Factory1
    {
        get { return factory1.Value; }
    }
    public Factory2 Factory2
    {
        get { return factory2.Value; }
    }
    // etc
}
```

and use them this way:

```
Singletons.Factory1.For("ab-CD")
Singletons.Factory2.For("ef-GH")
```

`Lazy<T>` itself **is** a singleton implementation with lazy initialization. With the second boolean parameter `true` it is a thread-safe implementation. Hence, you don't need to wrap it, don't need to write all this locks and double-checking code.

Comment: It's not a very constructive post when you answer with two more questions. You might have a good point but I'm not clear what you're explaining. Could you fill out your example a bit more please?